# Install Appimage under Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, appimage

I've downloaded an appimage file and just want to install it. I know that it is pretty simple under Ubuntu and Fedora, but I struggle to get it installed under Arch Linux. Is there a common way to install the program?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`.appimage` files are just complete app executables (similar to but not exactly equivalent of `.app` pseudo-files on macOS), so they do not require installation. If you really want to be able to call them from anywhere, you can put them in `/usr/local/bin`, but that is unnecessary. If I understood correctly, you are using them in a Desktop/Laptop machine, so even putting them on the desktop does the trick.

To be able to execute a `.appimage` file, it has to be set as an executable, by changing your permissions for it. This is easily done using the command:

```
chmod +x /path/to/file
```

in which `/path/to/file` is the path to the `.appimage` file you wish to run. Once it has been set as executable, you can open it like any other file.

**Note that, provided the distro you are using supports AppImages (and most do), the procedure is the same for any, not just for Arch specifically.**

Comment: you might need to install fuse2/fuse3 package (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/fuse2/)

Answer (score 5):

AppImage requires fuse to mount the embedded sqashfs filesystem.

If fuse is not installed, you can use the parameter `--appimage-extract-and-run`.

This extracts the application and starts it.

**Manual steps to extract and run an AppImage:**

If you want to extract the contents of the AppImage can use `--appimage-extract`. This also allows to modify the files from the extracted application.

After extracting the data you have a folder named `squashfs-root` and in this folder, there is an executable called `AppRun`.

Executing `AppRun` should work on most Linux distributions, as long as the application was built for your architecture.